# Show Videos from auto-generated youtube channel (Most Popular)

Tags: java, youtube

I started migrating to Youtube API v3.

I would like to show videos listed on "http://www.youtube.com/channel/HC4qRk91tndwg" using Youtube API v3.

As you can see, from that youtube channel, there are 10 topics: most popular, Cars & Vehicles, Comedy, Entertainment, and so on.

I have tried using the playlists API, assuming each topics listed in that channel page is a playlist.

GET "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=id%2Csnippet&channelId=HC4qRk91tndwg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}"

It gives me only the first playlist item, which is the "Most Popular".

My question is that how do I get the rest of the playlists, such as Entertainment or Music on that page.

Comment: 1) You've described a specification, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question? 2) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have re-worded my questions.  Hopefully, now it is clear.